# Bootstrap flex equal width columns without html table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, html-table, flexbox

Is there a way with this flex layout to get the scores to line up correctly without using a table?  The highlighted parts should be lined up as above and below correctly, but since 9 has less length then 15, the columns look uneven.  Is there  away to accomplish this with flex outside of a table?

[image]

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card" style="width:400px">
    <div class="card-header text-center d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="mr-1 flex-shrink-0" style="min-width:0" data-bind="html: TimeFormatted">3:10 PM EDT</div><div class="d-flex text-truncate">@<span class="text-truncate mx-1">Wabash Valley Family Sports Center</span> (<span>Larry Wilson Court</span>)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="text-truncate mr-auto">
                    <a target="_blank" href="/157555/fall-volleyball-league/teams/team-christner?divisionteamid=1591685">Team Christner</a><span data-bind="visible: AwayTeamExhibition" style="display: none;">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex">
                <span class="final-score">1</span>
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">14</span>
                
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">25</span>
                
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">9</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex font-weight-bold">
            <div class="text-truncate mr-auto">
                    <a target="_blank" href="/157555/fall-volleyball-league/teams/team-mikuly?divisionteamid=1591686">Team Mikuly</a><span 
 style="display: none;">*</span>
        
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex">
                <span class="final-score">2</span>

                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">25</span>
                
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">12</span>
                
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">15</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer d-flex">
        <div class="text-truncate mr-auto"><span>3rd-5th Grade</span>, <span>Pool A</span></div>
        <div class=""">Final</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-center">
           
            <a target="_blank" title="Directions" href="http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=39.4564711,-87.2602811" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></a>
               
         
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can have a container with a set width and inside it you use col 4 times (without anything so it autodivides) and use w-100 to break after the first 4 elements?

Comment: I think it would also help to have them left aligned.

Comment: @AlePlo it is left aligned just has a margin left

Answer (score 1):

give the score a `min-width` (or `width`) equal to two numbers

```css
[class*="score"] {
  min-width:2ch;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card" style="width:400px">
    <div class="card-header text-center d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="mr-1 flex-shrink-0" style="min-width:0" data-bind="html: TimeFormatted">3:10 PM EDT</div><div class="d-flex text-truncate">@<span class="text-truncate mx-1">Wabash Valley Family Sports Center</span> (<span>Larry Wilson Court</span>)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="text-truncate mr-auto">
                    <a target="_blank" href="/157555/fall-volleyball-league/teams/team-christner?divisionteamid=1591685">Team Christner</a><span data-bind="visible: AwayTeamExhibition" style="display: none;">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex">
                <span class="final-score">1</span>
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">14</span>
                
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">25</span>
                
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">9</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex font-weight-bold">
            <div class="text-truncate mr-auto">
                    <a target="_blank" href="/157555/fall-volleyball-league/teams/team-mikuly?divisionteamid=1591686">Team Mikuly</a><span 
 style="display: none;">*</span>
        
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex">
                <span class="final-score">2</span>

                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">25</span>
                
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">12</span>
                
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">15</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer d-flex">
        <div class="text-truncate mr-auto"><span>3rd-5th Grade</span>, <span>Pool A</span></div>
        <div class=""">Final</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-center">
           
            <a target="_blank" title="Directions" href="http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=39.4564711,-87.2602811" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></a>
               
         
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Learned. 'min-width:2ch;' looks great!

Comment: 1 comment for this answer, the min-width should be set to the possible maximumx length of the score. If the biggest score is 100 then, it should be set to 3ch, if it is 99,  and 2ch should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

as like Temani Afif advice you can use min-width for scores, and you can also use min-width for the whole div and use justify-content as space-evenly. But please note that if you are dynamic score, and the width is greater than the min-width it will not align evenly in this answer.

```css
.score{
  min-width:100px;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card" style="width:400px">
    <div class="card-header text-center d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="mr-1 flex-shrink-0" style="min-width:0" data-bind="html: TimeFormatted">3:10 PM EDT</div><div class="d-flex text-truncate">@<span class="text-truncate mx-1">Wabash Valley Family Sports Center</span> (<span>Larry Wilson Court</span>)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="text-truncate mr-auto">
                    <a target="_blank" href="/157555/fall-volleyball-league/teams/team-christner?divisionteamid=1591685">Team Christner</a><span data-bind="visible: AwayTeamExhibition" style="display: none;">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex score">
                <span class="final-score">1</span>
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">14</span>
                
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">25</span>

                
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">9</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex font-weight-bold">
            <div class="text-truncate mr-auto">
                    <a target="_blank" href="/157555/fall-volleyball-league/teams/team-mikuly?divisionteamid=1591686">Team Mikuly</a><span 
 style="display: none;">*</span>
        
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex score">
                <span class="final-score">2</span>

                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">25</span>
                
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">12</span>
                
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">15</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer d-flex">
        <div class="text-truncate mr-auto"><span>3rd-5th Grade</span>, <span>Pool A</span></div>
        <div class=""">Final</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-center">
           
            <a target="_blank" title="Directions" href="http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=39.4564711,-87.2602811" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></a>
               
         
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to write custom css property if you are using **Bootstrap-4** there is **predefine classes** for width like class **w-50** means **width: 50%** and if you want transfer element to right side then use class **justify-content-end** in display **flex**.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="card" style="width:400px">
    <div class="card-header text-center d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="mr-1 flex-shrink-0" style="min-width:0" data-bind="html: TimeFormatted">3:10 PM EDT</div><div class="d-flex text-truncate">@<span class="text-truncate mx-1">Wabash Valley Family Sports Center</span> (<span>Larry Wilson Court</span>)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="w-50 text-truncate mr-auto">
                <a target="_blank" href="/157555/fall-volleyball-league/teams/team-christner?divisionteamid=1591685">Team Christner</a><span data-bind="visible: AwayTeamExhibition" style="display: none;">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="w-50 d-flex justify-content-end">
                <span class="final-score">1</span>
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">14</span>
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">25</span>
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">9</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex font-weight-bold">
            <div class="w-50 text-truncate mr-auto">
                <a target="_blank" href="/157555/fall-volleyball-league/teams/team-mikuly?divisionteamid=1591686">Team Mikuly</a><span style="display: none;">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="w-50 d-flex justify-content-end">
                <span class="final-score">2</span>
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">25</span>
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">12</span>
                <span class="other-score font-weight-normal ml-2">15</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer d-flex">
        <div class="text-truncate mr-auto"><span>3rd-5th Grade</span>, <span>Pool A</span></div>
        <div class="">Final</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-center">
        <a target="_blank" title="Directions" href="http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=39.4564711,-87.2602811" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Map</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grid.

Make the card body a container then use rows and columns like you see in the snippet. I set the name column to `.col-6` to take up half the width and the score columns to just `.col` to take up even amount of remaining space. I also gave the score columns `.text-right` and `.text-monospace` to ensure the the columns of numbers also line-up across the rows.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card" style="width:400px">
  <div class="card-header text-center d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="mr-1 flex-shrink-0" style="min-width:0" data-bind="html: TimeFormatted">3:10 PM EDT</div>
    <div class="d-flex text-truncate">
      @<span class="text-truncate mx-1">Wabash Valley Family Sports Center</span> (<span>Larry Wilson Court</span>)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-6 text-truncate">
        <a target="_blank" href="/157555/fall-volleyball-league/teams/team-christner?divisionteamid=1591685">Team Christner</a><span data-bind="visible: AwayTeamExhibition" style="display: none;">*</span>
      </div>

      <span class="col text-right text-monospace final-score">1</span>
      <span class="col text-right text-monospace other-score font-weight-normal">14</span>
      <span class="col text-right text-monospace other-score font-weight-normal">25</span>
      <span class="col text-right text-monospace other-score font-weight-normal">9</span>

    </div>

    <div class="row font-weight-bold">

      <div class="col-6 text-truncate">
        <a target="_blank" href="/157555/fall-volleyball-league/teams/team-mikuly?divisionteamid=1591686">Team Mikuly</a><span style="display: none;">*</span>
      </div>

      <span class="col text-right text-monospace final-score">2</span>
      <span class="col text-right text-monospace other-score font-weight-normal">25</span>
      <span class="col text-right text-monospace other-score font-weight-normal">12</span>
      <span class="col text-right text-monospace other-score font-weight-normal">15</span>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer d-flex">
    <div class="text-truncate mr-auto"><span>3rd-5th Grade</span>, <span>Pool A</span></div>
    <div class="">Final</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer text-center">

    <a target="_blank" title="Directions" href="http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=39.4564711,-87.2602811" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></a>


  </div>
</div>
```